# Is there a way to check propTypes for observer(Component)

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react, react-proptypes

For example, in this case, if I pass `ObservedA` to `B` as `Comp`:

```js
const ObservedA = observer(class A extends React.Component {});

function B({Comp}) {
  return <Comp />;
}

B.propTypes = {
  Comp: PropTypes.node // Warning!
};
```

A warning occurs:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `Comp` supplied to `B`, expected a ReactNode.

Is there a way to check `propTypes` for `observer(Component)`?

Comment: You can create [custom PropType](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) with typeof inside or better use Typescript :)

Comment: Why do you want to check for the component to be observed? Does that matter for `B`? Wouldn't `PropTypes.elementType()` be sufficient?

Comment: @trixn `PropTypes.elementType()` is for specific element type, isn't it? `Comp` would be any elements. `ObservedA` is an example.

Comment: @YonggooNoh No it's not for a specific element type. It checks if the prop is of a valid renderable type (any type) including class components, functional components,  providers, portals and so on. See [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/211) for details. I think it is better suited for your use case than `PropTypes.func` as this wouldn't work for e.g. a context provider.

Comment: @trixn Ah that's what I want! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the `Comp` prop is a type that can be rendered, you can use [`PropTypes.elementType`](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/211) starting with `prop-types 15.7.0`:

```
B.propTypes = {
  Comp: PropTypes.elementType
};
```

It will be valid for every renderable type, including e.g. context providers.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a proper way to check `observer(Component)` but I've got to know that babel transpiles `class` to `function() {}`. So I just checked the prop by `func` like:

```js
B.propTypes = {
  Comp: PropTypes.func
};
```

I think it's one of solutions but not proper.